# OS X equivalent to resizableImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiimage, nsimage

Is there an equivalent to the iOS methods `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]` and `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:]` for `NSImage` on MacOS X?

I've looked at `NSImage` docs and can't see anything.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14698878/730701).

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case :D